# Why Cant I use basic hover and active css on xcode cordova application

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Im having problem with cordova xcode app. I already have my html page setup. I cant make a very simple hover and active animation on css. Very basic, when you click or hover a certain button or div tag, background image will change. I already tried javascript/jquery (created a function for mouseDown and Up) but nothing happened. I think cordova app or the xcode itself prevent such style or animation? If so, can I edit it make my own style.?

Well, before I export in my IOS app I tried it in dreamweaver and ran it on the browser and it worked. But when I export it on my ios app the css/javascript hover no longer work.

Should you have answer any answer regarding this matter is highly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think cordova app or the xcode itself prevent such style or
>   animation? If so, can I edit it make my own style.?

I was able to do a simple animation in cordova. For instance:

```
$('#formulaire').animate({
                            opacity: 1.0,
                        }, 4000, function() {});


$('#logo').animate({
                    "top":"60px"
                   }, 2000, function() {});
}
```

**Edit 1.0:**

> Inside the html file (index)?

Yes.

> How did you configure your cordova app.

Just like it's state on the quick guide in the cordova site.

So my question here, are you using JQuery? Did you import it correctly? Mine is imported like this:

```
 <script  src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script  src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Don't mind the Data Management folder:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jacky Boy., Thanks for your sample. Where did you put your code. Inside the html file (index)? Or some where in the folders in your app project. I just cant make any anymation. How did you configure your cordova app. Me, I just created a file turn off automatic reference counting if that I can remember correctly and drag the www folder in my project and that's is. I just really cant do the hover thing. Its so frustrating. Cant find any answer on the web why or what ive done wrong or missed.

Comment: Got to be honest with you ray, nothing like going native... ;) But check my edit..

Comment: Hi @Jacky Boy. Thank you very much! Well actually, I checked my config based on what you posted. Ive realized nothing's really different. But I still have the same problem. As what I have mentioned my problem is the active and hover thing in css/javascript.

Comment: So, I did test other simple animation. The onClick thing and change the background image, it worked on my app but there is a delay. Probably that is what causing the problem. We'll Im not really sure. Have you tried hover in your app? Also I have another problem, I put input text on my html. Xcode read input text and shows keyboard once it is clicked. I did not connect it to the view controller coz I never knew that. Hehe.. Basically Im just doing pure html. Just editing index.html file.

Comment: Should you have answer kindly let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I almost don't have experience with cordova, but what I was able to achieve was always with HTML..

Comment: Be aware that touch interfaces don't have a 'hover' state, they can't detect when a finger is hovering over elements.  It's obvious when you handle a device, but not when you use the simulator as you still have a pointer!  You can only detect the actual touch.  On iOS there is a 0.25 second delay on 'onClick' events, I've never heard a rational explanation as to why Apple introduced this, but for an immediate response, use 'onTouchStart' instead.

Comment: @Purpletoucan Thanks for the explanation. Really well explained. Never thought of that.